# Forcing custom resolution in windows 7 without a monitor (connecting via Teamviewer)

Tags: windows-7, resolution, teamviewer

I have a computer that I control using teamviewer only.
When I connect to the computer, the resolution is 640x480.
I tried changing the registry values of DefautlSettings.XResolution and DefautlSettings.YResolution, and I tried disabling the TMM.
Nothing helped.

The computer has R9 290x GPU.

How can I change the resolution?

Thanks for your help,

yuval.

Comment: Try forcing resolution in Catalyst Control Center instead of registry.
Issue is mainly connected with the fact that device has no external display device detected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set default screen resolution without monitor in windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/604026/how-to-set-default-screen-resolution-without-monitor-in-windows-7)

Comment: Perhaps try a DVI/VGA terminator plug to force it into thinking it's got a monitor: http://www.overclock.net/t/384733/the-30-second-dummy-plug

Comment: Why not use RDP?

Answer (score 2):

If your host display adapter allows you to add custom resolutions, you can set one up and use it in teamviewer settings when connecting to that computer.

I have Nvidia GF 9300 M and my laptop display only allows up to 1280 x 800. I defined a 1440 x 900 custom resolution. That's how I overcame this issue when I connect to my laptop from my desktop.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Regards