# When no monitor connect , the resolution can only be 1920 * 1080 in 30hz?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution, vga

I am using windows 7, and ati 7850 display card.

I would like to use the computer without monitor , and when I use teamviewer to control it, I found that the monitor detect is VGA , and the maximum resolution is 1600 * 1200 (60hz) or 1920 * 1080 (30hz).

Any idea about this? Since when I would like to use steam for game streaming it only let me select the 1600 * 1200, and there is no 1920 * 1080 choice, therefore, how can I set 1920 * 1080 60hz without monitor?

Thanks

Comment: That's odd. It shouldn't detect a display at all. What are you using for game streaming?

Comment: steam but I dobut it is related as the main problem is can not set the display to 1920 * 1080 * 60hz

Comment: follow this? but seems quite complicated

http://www.ehow.com/how_7649449_add-custom-resolution-ati.html

Comment: I don't think that the monitor being present or not is significant. If you connect a monitor, what is the maximum resolution allowed? Have you looked in Windows Update, optional section, for updates to the video driver? You could also check the dricer using the [AMD Driver Autodetect](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool).

Comment: thanks. when I connect the monitor , the ati panel setting has a hdtv option and I can select the 1080p

Comment: Have you got  **Hide modes that this monitor cannot display** option un-checked?

Comment: sure did this. thanks for helping. anyway , giveup streaming as it shutter during the gaming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you connecting a monitor or a TV?

Below are some methods that could perhaps solve the problem,
singly or several together :

**Method 1 : Use a tool to force the resolution**

Here are some command line tools that can change the screen resolution :
[QRes](http://qres.sourceforge.net/), [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), [Display Changer](http://12noon.com/?page_id=80).

**Method 2 : Registry updates**

Search the registry for `DefaultSettings.XResolution`, `DefaultSettings.YResolution` and `BitsPerPixel` and change
to the desired resolution.

If necessary, add ColorDepth for RDP connection :

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]
>   "ColorDepth"=dword:00000003 in decimal.

More info can be [found here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-changes-screen-resolution-on-boot-up/13c17468-0d70-4827-a559-dca0fa558a69?auth=1).

**Method 3 : Setting the video adapter to custom setting**

If your VGA video driver has customizing software, you could do something similar to:

[image]

**Method 4 : Use a fake video plug**

If it becomes necessary to fool Windows into believing that a real
monitor is attached, see this tutorial on how to create such a plug using
a spare DVI-VGA adapter and three 68 ohm resistors:
[The 30 Second Dummy Plug](http://www.overclock.net/t/384733/the-30-second-dummy-plug).

[image]

**Method 5 : Use PowerStrip** (shareware, $29.95)

The [PowerStrip utility](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) allows you to gain complete control over the video card.
For more details see :
[Customize monitor resolution settings with PowerStrip](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customize-monitor-resolution-settings-with-powerstrip/1046725/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

here is a copy & paste form [this](https://superuser.com/questions/604026/how-to-set-default-screen-resolution-and-color-depth-without-monitor-in-windows/605865#605865) form:

First set desired resolution using:

> ControlPanel → Display → Screen Resolution.

Also set `ColorDepth` using:

> ControlPanel→ Display → Screen Resolution → Advance Settings → Monitor → Color

After this in `regedit`, manually search for `DefaultSettings.XResolution`, `DefaultSettings.YResolution` and `BitsPerPixel` and change all those to 1920, 1200, 16 (All in Decimal) respectively using next search button <kbd>F3</kbd>.
I also added entry of ColorDepth for RDP connection(not mandatory)::

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services]
>   "ColorDepth"=dword:00000003 in decimal.

I don't know, which portion of registry did this, but now it works.