# How do I change Windows 10 to a resolution for a screen that's not connected?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution, 4k-resolution

I ship hardware packages containing an Intel NUC and a 4K monitor (double HD, 3840x2160). The NUC computers are loaded using 1920x1080 displays, which means when the packages are delivered and the NUC connects to the 4K display it will be set to 1920x1080 resolution instead of 3840x2160. The video card supports 4K of course, so how do I set Windows 10 to 3840x2160 while the NUC is connected to a screen with a max resolution of 1920x1080? I don't know if there's any way to do that at all so I feel bad adding more requirements onto that, but ideally this needs to be automated with a script.

Comment: Every new display should make windows try and set its resolution to the native one, so normally it would set the nuk to 4K if its a new monitor.

Comment: Have you searched online? See, for example, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/07/07/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-change-my-desktop-monitor-resolution-via-windows-powershell/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, I have searched. That's a nice link and it may be helpful, but it doesn't seem to address the specific question of changing resolution to one that's not supported on the current screen. The closest thing I found to my question is this: https://superuser.com/questions/934868/when-no-monitor-connect-the-resolution-can-only-be-1920-1080-in-30hz

Comment: @LPChip We've observed it not doing this. If you set Windows to a non-native resolution, would it still try to set its resolution to the native one on the new display? Is there any Windows setting that determines whether its resolution is fixed or if it's "auto" (meaning it will dynamically change to a new screen's default)?

Comment: Ah, I assumed the 1080p resolution was native. if you go non-native windows doesn't do that indeed. But it should if you set it to the native resolution.

Comment: @LPChip I'm pretty sure 1080p is native. That's why I'm asking if there's anything else I need to do beyond setting it to the native resolution to enable the auto-resolution behavior.

Comment: Can you do setup using the 3840x2160 monitor before shipping?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It would mean a considerable drop in efficiency, which is why I'm here looking for a better option.

Comment: *"It would mean a considerable drop in efficiency..."*  I'll bite: how so?  It sounds like a very logical step to install and configure the operating system environment on the same hardware that it will eventually use full-time.

Comment: @Run2K I don't know that I can answer that to anyone's satisfaction, and I don't see how it would contribute to obtaining an answer to the question that I asked. But it has something to do with the 4K displays being too large to fit on the "assembly line" being used to load the small computers.