# How to fake a primary monitor

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I have a computer that I use for automated UI-tests (opening our application, clicking buttons, verifying that the expected outcomes happen). The only external cables are power, DVI to monitor, and cable to wifi antenna. I control the computer through LAN and VNC, so I have no use for mouse/keyboard. The monitor it is connected to is only used on my primary computer.

My goal is to get rid of this extra cable to the monitor.

If I unplug the monitor-cable, Windows sets the resolution to be 800x600, which is to small for me (I need 1920x1080). Connecting through VNC will give me a higher resolution. Once I connect the monitor it becomes 1920x1080, even though the monitor itself is powered off.

Does anyone know how I can trick Windows 7 to have full resolution(1920x1080) without having a monitor connected, and still allow for connection through VNC?

Comment: Have you seen these threads? http://superuser.com/questions/120983/how-to-disable-monitor-auto-detection-in-windows-7 & http://superuser.com/questions/604026/how-to-set-default-screen-resolution-and-color-depth-without-monitor-in-windows